# command not found (2 lines) when opening the terminal

Tags: command-line

As soon as I open my terminal I get:

```
$: command not found 
$: command not found
```

Even if I close and open again I get the same.

```
$: command not found
$: command not found
```

How to sort out this problem?

Comment: Have you edited your .bash_profile (or one of the other alternatives) to modify your prompt or other? and introduced a typing error? or added something that did work, but have recently (since just before the error started appearing) removing a program which now produces the error? I would check these files and look for errors, especially files you've modified since install (`ls -ltrha` may provide a clue).... This is just a guess

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu uses `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` and I guess the problem should raise from `.bashrc` because `.profile` and `.bash_profile` only get sourced once at login time and not every time you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

First run this command:

```
grep -E '^\$' .bashrc -c
```

It should give you a number greater than of 0, which means your `.bashrc` contains some lines started with `$`.

Run this command:

```
sed -r -i.bak 's/^\$.*//' .bashrc .profile
```

it should fix the issue by editing and removing the offending lines in your `.bashrc` and `.profile` files. The original files will be backed up with the `.bak` suffix.

---

There is two `$` somewhere in your `.bashrc`, every time you open a new terminal `.bashrc` will be sourced and thus bash try to run the `$` as command which there is no such a command and bash complains about it with `command not found`.

Comment: @Melebius yep that would cause the problem too.

Comment: @Melebius Updated ...

Comment: I am getting the number 0.

Comment: @pranav try running a new terminal... Are you still getting the errors?

Comment: No, now I am not getting the error.

Comment: @pranav so  running the `sed` command fixed the issue by removing the `$` from `.bashrc`.

Comment: @pranav I also updated my answer... you have to run `grep` before the `sed` ... if you get `0` by running `grep` then there is no problem any more ;)

Comment: I ended up ruining the edited ~ / .bashrc with the vi and forgot to fix it. This tip of yours led me to the cause of the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pereira Glad that it helped you ;)